# Run web.py as daemon

Tags: python, backgroundworker

I have a simple web.py program to load data. In the server I don't want to install apache or any webserver.

I try to put it as a background service with http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/

And subclassing:
(from http://www.jejik.com/files/examples/daemon.py)

```
class Daemon:
    def start(self):
        """
        Start the daemon
        """
        ... PID CHECKS....

        # Start the daemon
        self.daemonize()
        self.run()
#My code
class WebService(Daemon):
        def run(self):
            app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if DEBUG:
        app.run()
    else:
        service = WebService(os.path.join(DIR_ACTUAL,'ElAdministrador.pid'))
        if len(sys.argv) == 2:
            if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
                service.start()
            elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
                service.stop()
            elif 'restart' == sys.argv[1]:
                service.restart()
            else:
                print "Unknown command"
                sys.exit(2)
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            print "usage: %s start|stop|restart" % sys.argv[0]
            sys.exit(2)
```

However, the web.py software not load (ie: The service no listen)

If I call it directly (ie: No using the daemon code) work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally find the problem.

Web.py accept from command-line the optional port number:

```
python code.py 80
```

And the script also take input from the command-line:

```
python WebServer start
```

then web.py try to use "start" as port number and fail. I don't see the error because was in the bacground.

I fix this with a mini-hack:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if DEBUG:
        app.run()
    else:
        service = WebService(os.path.join(DIR_ACTUAL,'ElAdministrador.pid'))
        if len(sys.argv) == 2:
            if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
                sys.argv[1] = '8080'
                service.start()
```

Answer (score 5):

you can start the web.py by using this command

```
/usr/bin/python index.py > log.txt 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're telling the daemon to run. You need to instantiate a MyDaemon object and call o.run(). It looks like WebService only starts and stops the service interface to your web app, not the actual web app itself.

Comment: I update the question to show that when call "start" is called the "run" method.

Comment: I still can't tell how service (from WebService) connects to MyDaemon, unless it's implicit.

Comment: Oh, my mistake :(. I forget to put the correct className (bad kittie copy/paste!)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overwrite the second argument like you wrote here:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if DEBUG:
        app.run()
    else:
        service = WebService(os.path.join(DIR_ACTUAL,'ElAdministrador.pid'))
        if len(sys.argv) == 2:
            if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
                sys.argv[1] = '8080'
                service.start()
```

you could just delete the second argument on 'start|restart', like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if DEBUG:
        app.run()
    else:
        service = WebService(os.path.join(DIR_ACTUAL,'ElAdministrador.pid'))
        if len(sys.argv) == 2:
            if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
                delete del sys.argv[1:2]
                service.start()
```

In this way, the webpy will receive all the arguments you passed from command line except the daemon controller. Then you can run simply:

```
python WebServer start 8080
```